# Delete multiple rows with duplicate single column values based off column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary. I need to separate out by `PRESC LOCATION` and email the `PRESC` to show them the `ID` and the `DRUG` without duplicates.  I currently do that with `df.query` and iterate for unique values in column `LOCATION`.

My problem is when I remove duplicate `ID`, I'll email only one `PRESC` if there are multiple `PRESC`; ie here we see `SPARK` has A and B as `PRESC` getting `DRUG` 22.

Is there anyway I can avoid removing duplicate `ID` if their `PRESC` is not the same?

```py
technologies = {
  'ID':["Spark","Spark","Spark","Spark","Python"],
  'PRESC':["A","A","B","C","A"],
  'DRUG' :[22,22,22,22,30],
  'PRESC LOCATION':['RIV','RIV','RIV','COR','RIV'],
  'DATE':["2/16/2022 3:48", "3/16/2022 4:14","3/17/2022 4:00","4/1/2022 2:14","1/11/2022 3:00"]
}
```

Comment: Do you want the non duplicated list of `PRESC` per `ID` & `DRUG` combination?  => `df.groupby(['ID', 'DRUG']).agg({'PRESC': lambda x: set(x)})`

Comment: @emma non-duplicated list of ID with unique PRESC.

Comment: You can remove the 'DRUG' from `group` then.  Actually, `unique` is simpler than `set`.  `df.groupby(['ID']).PRESC.unique()`

Comment: @emma any tips on how to export to excel? aka turn it back into a dataframe vs groupbyobj?

Comment: add `reset_index()`.